# Redirect page-page & end slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, prestashop

I am facing a htaccess problem with a Prestashop.
I need to do remove all end slashs, but also make simple page redirects.

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 ^/old-url/$ https:/domain.io/newurl
Redirect 301 ^/old-url2/$ https:/domain.io/newurl2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But the problem is, that if https:/domain.io/old-url/ is entered, it redirects to frontpage... Its not processing the rule. I think its because it do not stop, but keeps processing.
How do I tell it to stop processing if simple redirect is true ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should only remove the end trailing slash and not redirect home